# MSSQL with Jboss

Tags: sql-server, jboss, server

I am trying to configure MSSQL with Jboss. I am getting exception where it says 
"JDBC Unable to get managed connection"

I have put the sqljdbc_auth.dll and sqljdbc_xa.dl in the jboss\server\lib 
Below is the config I have given in the mssql-ds.xml

```
 <datasources>
    <xa-datasource>
        <!-- JNDI name of the DataSource, to be prefixed with "java:/" upon reference -->
        <!-- DataSource are not available outside the virtual machine -->
        <jndi-name>jdbc/ds/mssqlDS</jndi-name>

        <!-- uncomment to enable interleaving <interleaving/> -->
        <isSameRM-override-value>false</isSameRM-override-value>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <!--<xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:sqlserver://ip:1433;databaseName=dev_sql</xa-datasource-property>-->
        <!-- Alternate way of configuration -->
        <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-property>
        <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">dev_sql</xa-datasource-property>

        <xa-datasource-property name="User">sa</xa-datasource-property>
        <xa-datasource-property name="Password">sql!23</xa-datasource-property>
        <xa-datasource-property name="SelectMethod">cursor</xa-datasource-property>

        <!-- Uses the pingDatabase method to check a connection is still valid before handing it out from the pool org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.ValidConnectionChecker -->
        <valid-connection-checker-class-name>org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker</valid-connection-checker-class-name>

        <!-- Checks the SQL Server error codes and messages for fatal errors -->
        <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.SybaseExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>

        <!-- XA datasource cannot reuse a connection outside a transaction once enlisted in a global transaction and vice-versa -->
        <no-tx-separate-pools/>

        <!-- Sets the default date format for the session 
        <new-connection-sql>alter session set nls_date_format='FXDD-MON-YYYY' optimizer_mode='ALL_ROWS'</new-connection-sql>
        -->

        <!-- corresponding type-mapping in the standardjbosscmp-jdbc.xml (optional) -->
        <metadata>
            <type-mapping>MS SQLSERVER2000</type-mapping>
        </metadata>

        <!-- Database connection pooling settings -->
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>120</max-pool-size>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes>
    </xa-datasource>
</datasources>
```

I tried using tx with the below config

```
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/ds/sqlDS</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://ip:1433;databaseName=dev_sql</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
    <user-name>sa</user-name>
    <password>sql!23</password>
  </local-tx-datasource>

</datasources>
```

Any leads ?

Stack trace
Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:498)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    com.chess.elcm.i9n.client.ViewHandler.gotoNextView(ViewHandler.java:367)
    ..client.ViewHandler.gotoNextPage(ViewHandler.java:78)
    ..elcm.i9n.client.Controller.service(Controller.java:200)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

Root cause
BusinessException: Unable to communicate with the datasource.

Comment: Do you have any other error or stacktrace in your logs? And which version of Jboss are you using?

Comment: Here is the cause which I got when I tried debugging via ecilipse.
Cause : org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Unable to get managed connection for sql/sqlDS; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Unable to get managed connection for jdbc/elcm/ClientDS)
detail message : Cannot open connection
I don't find a log file in the log folder. I am not sure if the logger is working proper ! The jboss version which I use is jboss610

Comment: It happens always? The message "Unable to get managed connection for" sometimes is throwed because all connections in the pool are in use. Perhaps you can take a look on your console to see how many connections are open (or from the command line with netstat to see if there are established connections against the database).

Comment: It always shows the mentioned error. Please check my updated description where I have posted the stack trace.

Comment: I'm afraid this error doesn't provide enough information, perhaps the exception is controlled on the code. Perhaps you can deploy a simple app with tries to perform a query on the DB to see if in this way it Throws an exception with more information.

Comment: @aphamikevictor Thanks for the help. I have missed out the instance name. Now it is working good :-)

Comment: glad you resolve your problem. I suggest you to Answer yourself with the solution, so if any other user is getting the same/similar problem then can find another thing to try :)